# How to access the value of an attribute from xml using Lib XML parsing in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, attributes, xml-parsing, libxml2

I have chosen the lib xml technique to parse the data from xml parser. But I don't know how to extract the attribute value of a node in xml parser.

Please suggest any solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just after a value and you are not walking through the XML tree then you need to learn about XPaths for it I have the XML doc

```
<a>
 <b>
  <c att="foo"/>
 </b>
 <b>
  <c att="bar"/>
 </b>
</a>
```

then you path to get the value of *bar* would be something like this (I haven't done any path for a little while so this may not be exactly right.

```
/a/b[2]/c/@att/text()
```

libxml2 has function for dealing with paths, just make sure when google for information of xpaths you specify xpath v1 since libxml2 does not support xpath2.